# C/C++ sound library for musical instruments where you can manipulate the audio data

Tags: c++, audio, instruments

I'm looking for a C/C++ library for generating various instruments, and where I can subsequently manipulate the created audio data
For example, something like this:

```
Sound s = makeSound("piano",440,44100,1000);
```

Where "piano" is the type of instrument, 440 is the frequency of the tone, 44100 is the sample frequency and 1000 the  duration. The Sound s would be the audio data that can be used for further processing.

I've looked at some libraries, but CSound doesn't really allow the further processing of the generated audio (I think... I'm no expert), and I can't get STK (Synthesis Toolkit) to work (under windows anyway)
Any ideas? Help would be much appreciated.
Help about working with STK would be great too, because I think STK can do what I need.

Sincerely,
Sam

Comment: STK may indeed be able to do what you're looking for. But if you want us to help you using it, you have to provide us with more information about your problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i dont know can it beuseful for your purpose but you can look for [FMOD](http://www.fmod.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've looked into FMOD and it doesn't seem to do exactly what I want, it's mostly used for loading in soundfiles from the hdd and processing those, but I'm looking for something that can actually generate sounds